# How to install Clang 3.9 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, clang, carla

I am trying to install Carla in the stable version (0.8.2) and to use it I need to install Clang 3.9 which is not currently available using apt.
How do I install it?

Comment: I also need to isntall clang-3.9 on Linux Mint 21 x86_64

Answer (score 0):

Version specific CARLA document shows proper install commands.
https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.12/build_linux/ (see `https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/{VERSION}/build_linux/`)

For example, 0.9.12 shows `sudo apt install clang-8`.